# ActionScript 3 - set text of textField inside a movieClip through a variable

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

There's a movieClip on stage with the instance name of `movieClipA` which contains a `textField` with the instance name of `myTextField`.

There's also a string variable named `whichTextField` which it's value is set to `myTextField`.

```
var whichTextField:String = "myTextField";
movieClipA.myTextField.text = "ABC"; // WORKS.

movieClipA.whichTextField.text = "ABC"; // DOESN'T WORK.
```

how can I use the word `whichTextField` in my code to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with a little bit search I found this solution. please share yours if you can think of anything else:

```
var whichTextField:String = "myTextField";
movieClipA.myTextField.text = "ABC"; // WORKS.

// movieClipA.whichTextField.text = "ABC"; // DOESN'T WORK.
this["movieClipA"].getChildByName(whichTextField).text = "ABC"; // WORKS!
```

I also found another solution if `movieClipA` is inside another movieClip like `movieClipB`.
then this syntax would solve the problem:

```
movieClipB.movieClipA.getChildByName(whichTextField).text = "ABC";
```

this syntax also works:

```
movieClipB["movieClipA"].getChildByName(whichTextField).text = "ABC";
```

in general, if the instance is on stage, you can use dot notation or brackets. but if the instance is added through actionscript, you should use `getChildByName`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var whichTextField:String = "myTextField";
movieClipA.myTextField.text = "ABC"; // WORKS.

movieClipA[whichTextField].text = "ABC"; // WORKS.
```